# Creating Flask-flash in bootstrap example page

Tags: html, flask, jinja2, bootstrap-5

I am trying to display a flash message in Flask, I used to use the code:

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %} {% if
    messages %} {% for category, message in messages %} {% if category ==
    'error' %}

    <div class="alert alert-danger alter-dismissable fade show mt-5" role="alert">
      {{ message }}
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    {% else %}
    <div class="alert alert-success alter-dismissable fade show mt-5" role="success">
      {{ message }}
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    {% endif %} {% endfor %} {% endif %} {% endwith %}
```

However, now the X to close the flash message is hugging the text instead of aligned far right and nothing happens when you click the X which used to close the flash message. The only thing I am doing differently than before is upgrading the bootstrap CSS and JS to the latest version.

If someone could help me with the classes that would be great, there are many of them, and I do not see such an example anywhere on the web.

I expected a colored div with text in it aligned left and an X at the far right of the div and when you click the X the flash message closes. However, I am using newer bootstrap code and this code above does not work nor display correctly.

The page I am flashing is [www.mslscript.com/login.html](http://www.mslscript.com/login.html)